# Counting number of elements to be sorted in insertion sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-3.x

I think the title is self-explanatory. I am trying to write a program that could count how many swaps are needed to sort a list using insertion sort. This is what I have done:

```
counts = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    size = int(input())
    ar = list(map(int, input().split()))
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(ar)):
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):
            if ar[j] > ar[i]: count +=1
    counts.append(count)
print(*counts)
```

But the problem is that it's not working.

For list `{1 1 1 2 2}` I get `0` which is correct but,

for list `{2 1 3 1 2}` I get `2` which is not correct the answer is `4`.

Can I know why isn't it working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all couse of `for j in range(i, 0, -1):`. In `range` right bound is not included, so you should:

```
for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
```

Comment: Or: `reversed(range(i))` if using three arguments seems ugly.